# Error while rendering bundle product description page

Tags: bundle, bundle-product, magento2.4.3.p1, product-type, magento2bundleproduct

How are doing guys? We have an issue related to bundle products. The bundle products are being created without any issues and appear on the frontend, but when I try clicking on them to enter PDP(product description page) it renders a bit, shows placeholders, and then throws an error(404 not found, but that I believe is shown anytime an error appears). When checking the exception log it shows:

```
2022-07-14 06:35:56] main.ERROR:
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Bundle\Model\Link::setExtensionAttributes() must be an
instance of Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkExtensionInterface,
instance of Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtension given,
called in /home/<project>/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php on line 125
{"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Bundle\\Model\\Link::setExtensionAttributes()
must be an instance of Magento\\Bundle\\Api\\Data\\LinkExtensionInterface,
instance of Magento\\Catalog\\Api\\Data\\ProductExtension given,
called in /home/<project>/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php
on line 125 at /home/<project>/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:174,
TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Bundle\\Model\\Link::setExtensionAttributes() must be an instance of
Magento\\Bundle\\Api\\Data\\LinkExtensionInterface, instance of Magento\\Catalog\\Api\\Data\\ProductExtension given,
called in /home/<project>/vendor/magento/framework/Api/DataObjectHelper.php
on line 125 at /home/<project>/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Link.php:214)"} []
```

The only similar issue I found was on [magento github repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12278), but to be honest, there is no solution and I don't really know what to do with it. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Do you have a custom extension that creates any extension attributes for Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I'm new to the project, so I'll ask around. Thanks for the tip, any other tips what should I also be looking for?